# BASH while loop to check lines in file displays too many times

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, echo

I am writing a script where I want to take each line from a file and check for a match in another file. 
If I find a match I want to say that I found a match and if not, say that I did not find a match.

The 2 files contain md5 hashes. The old file is the original and the new file is to check if there have been any changes since the original file.

original file: chksum
new file:chksum1

```
#!/bin/bash

while read e; do
     while read f; do
     if [[ $e = $f ]]
     then 
     echo $e "is the same"
     else
          if [[ $e != $f]]
          then
          echo $e "has been changed"
          fi
     fi
     done < chksum1
done < chksum
```

My issue is that for the files that have been changed I get an echo for every time the check in the loop is done and I only want it to display the file once and say that it was not found.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Can you post some sample from your file? IMO `awk` can do this better.

Comment: Why you don't want to use the `diff`? `diff chksum chksum1` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Minor addition: In the `else` part, you do not need to check if the values are different, because they are, for sure. Just echo the line.

Comment: +1! Thanks for the question! I have learned something again. I read `man bash` (again) and I found the `${var:+val}` and `${var+val}` behaves differently!

Comment: I tried using diff but I was having a hard time as I have to say which files have been edited and which files have not. diff showed me all the files and after trying combinations of options I decided to use a loop

Comment: @someguy You have it right. Keeping it simple doesn't look to be on the cards here. I posted a solution with `sort` and `uniq`, but `diff` works just as well, if not better.

Comment: @zacgalf What is wrong about `diff` with `-q` option?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the same script but put a reminder.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read e; do
    rem=0
        while read f; do
        if [[ $e = $f ]]
        then 
            rem=1
        fi
        done < chksum1
    if [[ rem = 1 ]] 
    then
        echo $e "is the same"
    else
        echo $e "has been changed"
    fi
done < chksum
```

This should work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You were real close.  This will work:

```
while read e; do
     while read f; do
     found=0
     if [[ $e = $f ]]
     then 
         # echo $e "is the same"
         found=1
         break
     fi
     done < chksum1
     if [ $found -ne 0 ]
     then
        echo "$e is the the same"
     else
        echo "$e has been changed"
     fi
done < chksum
```

Comment: I am not sure why, because your script makes sense to me but it is telling me that all the files have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit simplified version which avoid the multiple read of the same file ([bash](/questions/tagged/bash) 4.0 and above). I assume that the files contain unique filenames and the file format is the output of the [md5sum](/questions/tagged/md5sum) command.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash
while read md5 file; do hash[$file]=$md5; done <chksum
while read md5 file; do
  [ -z "${hash[$file]}" ] && echo "$file new file" && continue
  [ ${hash[$file]} == $md5 ] && echo "$file is same" && continue
  echo "$file has been changed"
done <chksum1
```

This script reads the first file to an associative array, called `hash`. The index is the name of the file, and the value is the MD5 checksum. The second loop reads the second checksum file; the file name is not in the `hash` it prints `file new file`; if it is in the `hash` and the value equals then it is the same file; if it does not equals it writes `file has been changed`.

Input files:

```
$ cat chksum
eed0fc0313f790cec0695914f1847bca  ./a.txt
9ee9e1fffbb3c16357bf80c6f7a27574  ./b.txt
a91a408e113adce865cba3c580add827  ./c.txt
$ cat chksum1
eed0fc0313f790cec0695914f1847bca  ./a.txt
8ee9e1fffbb3c16357bf80c6f7a27574  ./b.txt
a91a408e113adce865cba3c580add827  ./d.txt
```

Output:

```
./a.txt is same
./b.txt has been changed
./d.txt new file
```

**EXTENDED VERSION**

Also detect deleted files.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash
while read md5 file; do hash[$file]=$md5; done <chksum
while read md5 file; do
  [ -z "${hash[$file]}" ] && echo "$file new file" && continue
  if [ ${hash[$file]} == $md5 ]; then echo "$file is same"
  else echo "$file has been changed"
  fi
  unset hash[$file]
done <chksum1
for file in ${!hash[*]};{ echo "$file deleted file";}
```

Output:

```
./a.txt is same
./b.txt has been changed
./d.txt new file
./c.txt deleted file
```

Comment: This is a little ahead of me but I will run it and research it

Comment: I supposed if I changed md5 to a user input variable it would work for sha1,sha512,etc?

Comment: @BrantNanton: Some explanation added. You do not need to change the input variable, it is just a name. You need to create the files having the proper checksums. If the first column is the chekcsum and the second is the filename you do not need to change anything.

Comment: @BrantNanton: I saw your script and this answer should work with it sing any chekcsum calculation, if the first column is the checksum and the second is the file name.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am about to test it

Comment: I am an error. hash[$file]: bad array subscript. this is on the first line.

Comment: @zacgalf: what is your `bash` version? Associative arrays supprted only in `bash` 4.0 and above. Which line you add the extra `[]`?

Comment: @zacgalf: I tested both script again on 4.1.10 and they works fine. On 3.2.25 it stops saying: `./a.sh: line 15: declare: -A: invalid option`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest an alternate solution: How about you don't read line by line, but use `sort` and `uniq -c` to see if there are differences. There is no need for a loop where a simple pipe can do your job.

In this case you want all the lines that have changed in file `chksum1`, so

```
sort chksum chksum1 chksum1 | uniq -c | egrep '^\s+2\s' | sed 's%\s\+2\s%%'
```

This also reads `chksum1` only 2 times, as compared to the loop based example, which reads it once per line of `chksum`.

Reusing the input files from one of the other answers:

```
samveen@precise:~/so$ cat chksum
eed0fc0313f790cec0695914f1847bca  ./a.txt
9ee9e1fffbb3c16357bf80c6f7a27574  ./b.txt
a91a408e113adce865cba3c580add827  ./c.txt

samveen@precise:~/so$ cat chksum1
eed0fc0313f790cec0695914f1847bca  ./a.txt
8ee9e1fffbb3c16357bf80c6f7a27574  ./b.txt
a91a408e113adce865cba3c580add827  ./d.txt

samveen@precise:~/so$ sort chksum chksum1 chksum1 |uniq -c | egrep '^\s+2\s' |sed 's%\s\+2\s%%'
8ee9e1fffbb3c16357bf80c6f7a27574  ./b.txt
a91a408e113adce865cba3c580add827  ./d.txt
```

Another possible solution is (as suggested in the question's comments) to use `diff` in conjunction with `sort`:

```
diff <(sort chksum) <(sort chksum1) |grep '^>'
```

The output:

```
samveen@precise:~/so$ diff <(sort chksum) <(sort chksum1) |grep '^>'
> 8ee9e1fffbb3c16357bf80c6f7a27574  ./b.txt
> a91a408e113adce865cba3c580add827  ./d.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
diff -q chksum1 chksum
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the command grep. Every line that you read from chksum will serve as a search pattern in chksum1. If grep finds a match,the `"$?"` which contains the return value of the grep will be equal to `0`, otherwise, it will be equal to `1`

```
while read e; do  
  grep $e checksum1
  if[ $? == "0" ];then
     echo $e "is the same"
  else
     echo $e "has been changed"
  fi
done < chksum
```